# Why is the value of macro is not changing in a called function?

Tags: c, macros

I came across a program on one C aptitude question site

```
#define i 20

void fun();

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d..",i);
    fun();
    printf("%d",i);       
}

void fun() {
#undef i;
#define i 30
}
```

Here the output comes to be

```
20..20
```

But according to me it should be

```
20..30
```

Why dosen't the value of `i`  become 30 after call to `fun()`?

```
#define i 20

void fun();
 int main(void)
 {
 printf("%d..",i);
 #define i 50       
 printf("%d",i);       
}
```

But if i compile and run above program the output comes to be 20..50
So now how macro value is changing at runtime.

Comment: The answer lies in the distinction between the preprocessor and the compiler. Search the web for some info and it should be clear.

Comment: Macros are processed *before* running the program -- and even before compiling. Make your compiler write out the "preprocessed" code and you will see what `i` does. (Also: never include semicolons in a `define`. With your apparent level of experience, you **will** get some nasty surprises!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros cannot be changed at runtime. In your program the macro is changed by the preprocessor once before compiling so it's value in the compiled program is `30`.

You can read about it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

```
void fun() {
#undef i;
#define i 30
}
```

will actually be an empty function, the preprocessed program would be

```
void fun();
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d..",20);
    fun();
    printf("%d",20);
}
void fun() {
}
```

so you can see that the output is correct.

To generate the above **preprocessed** program you can use this with `gcc`

```
gcc -E -P source.c
```

is actually an empty function

Comment: But if do like printf("%d..",i);
#define i 50
printf("%d",i); The output becomes 20..50

Comment: `#define i 50 printf("%d", i)`? exactly like that? If you have a case that does that then please add it to your question to help you interpret what is actually going on.

Comment: Macros are replaced (as in plain text replacement) with their definition before even the compiler sees the code, far before runtime. If you redefine a macro, its value will be changed for all code that is lower in the code file than the redefinition but not any before it. If you put a `printf("%d\n", i); in `fun` after the second `#define`, you'll get the output `20 50 20`.

Comment: @iharob so in my editted code you mean that preprocessed code will be                                                                                                       void fun();
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d..",20);
    #define i 50
    printf("%d",50);
}

Comment: @SimerSarao try with `gcc -E -P` and see... It will be like Wintermute explained. Also, **Grzegorz Szpetkowski**'s answer addresses the issue more precisely in my opinion, please read it.

Comment: @SimerSarao; Before compilation, a program goes to preprocessing process. All preprocessors are processed in this phase. Read more about it [here](http://althing.cs.dartmouth.edu/local/www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigmil/RevEng/ch02.html).

Answer (score 3):

The proprocessor's directives are completely independent and separate to program's ordinary flow. The reason for this lies in *translation phases*, that are specified in C Standard. The processing stage (phases 1-4) is performed conceptually before proper compilation (phase 7). The unit obtained after preprocessing stage is called as *translation unit* and you can think of it as "starting point" for further translation, including proper compilation.

Your compiler may allow to inspect particular translation unit, so you get how it looks effectively. For example `gcc` has `-E` flag for that (by default, it outputs so called [linemarkers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html), but you can suppress them using `-P` flag). In your case it might look as:

```
$ gcc -E test.c 
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"


void fun();

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d..",20);
    fun();
    printf("%d",20);
}

test.c:13:9: warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive
void fun() {


}
```